# ¿Por qué aparecen signos de interrogación en el rendimiento de page speed insights cuando analizo un sitio web?

Tags: rendimiento, googlepagespeed

Intento realizar el análisis de velocidad de un sitio web en Page Speed Insights pero al analizarlo me salen signos de interrogación en el rendimiento y en las siguientes métricas da error con este mensaje: "Error!
No se ejecutó el recopilador necesario para traces"
¿A qué se debe?
¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Anteriormente realizaba el análisis sin problemas, obteniendo calificaciones de más de 50%.

[imagen del error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9FH1.png)

Ya intenté actualizar el navegador, limpiar cookies, hacerlo desde incógnito, incluso agregué al archivo robots.txt el código:

User-Agent: Googlebot
Allow: .js
Allow: .css

Comment: Hola. Todo apunta a que esa URL tarda demasiado tiempo en cargar. Revisa si tienes en ella imágenes demasiado pesadas o código que tarda mucho en procesar, o errores. Podría ayudar que abras la consola del navegador, la cual te dirá si hay errores.

Comment: Y si no es super secreta puedes poner el link acá y probamos.